# using log in numpy to solve for the loan repayment formula

Tags: python, numpy, math

I am solving for `n` in the loan repayment formula at http://financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html

This simplified version only has 1 value for `n`:

```
P = (r * PV) / (1 - (1 + r) ** -n)

P = payment
PV = present value
r = rate per period
n = number of periods
```

I believe I have solved for `n`:

```
P = (r * PV) / (1 - (1 + r)**-n)

P * (1 - (1 + r)**-n) = (r * PV)

1 - (1 + r)**-n = (r * PV) / P

1  = (r * PV / P) + (1 + r) ** -n

1  - (r * PV / P) = (1 + r) ** -n

1  - (r * PV / P) = 1 /(1 + r) ** n

((1 + r) ** n) * (1  - (r * PV / P)) = 1

(1 + r) ** n = 1 / (1  - (r * PV / P))

n * log(1 + r) = log(1 / (1  - (r * PV / P))) 

n  = log(1 / (1  - (r * PV / P))) / log(1 + r) # finally done!
```

My problem is converting this to python. When I do `log(3)` on my calculator I get `0.477`

When I use numpy I get:

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.log(3)
Out[2]: 1.0986122886681098

In [3]: numpy.log10(3)
Out[3]: 0.47712125471966244
```

Therefore as of now my assumption to translate to python using numpy is:

```
periods_of_time  = numpy.log10(1 / (1  - (r * PV / P))) / numpy.log10(1 + r)
```

This article shows how to solve for variables that are an exponent...you use log: http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/expolog_4.htm

When I run it as so I get an error:

```
def get_periods_from_payment(present_value, rate_per_period, payment):
    rate_as_decimal = rate_per_period / 100
    return log10(1 / (1  - (rate_per_period * present_value / payment))) / log10(1 + rate_per_period)

# test get_interest_paid_from_periods()
result = get_interest_paid_from_periods(35000, 0.5, 180)
print(result)
assert result == 18163
```

The error is:

```
$ python interest_calculator.py 
295.35
interest_calculator.py:59: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log10
  return log10(1 / (1  - (rate_per_period * present_value / payment))) / log10(1 + rate_per_period)
nan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interest_calculator.py", line 101, in <module>
    assert result == 180
AssertionError
```

A similar answer says this means there is a negative value in the exponent, but if I solved correctly it should work.

Comment: Why do you have the assertion at the end of the program? That's what's causing the error.

Comment: The assertion is a test to see if it works. It returns `nan` or not a number:

Comment: interest_calculator.py:59: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log10
  return log10(1 / (1  - (rate_per_period * present_value / payment))) / log10(1 + rate_per_period)
nan

Comment: I think you may need to divide the rate_per_period by 100 if it's a percentage.

Comment: ?You are trying to calculate the number of periods given payment, rate and starting value??

Comment: @wwii yes exactly

Comment: That is done in the line `rate_as_decimal = rate_per_period / 100`

Comment: I see I wasn't using it lol

Comment: Silly human, the computer is never wrong :P)

Comment: [Annuity (PV)- Solve for n](http://financeformulas.net/Number-of-Periods-of-Annuity-from-Present-Value.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `log` on your calculator is base 10 while `log` in Python is base *e*.
Since you're dividing a log by another log of the same base **it actually doesn't matter** which base you use for your logarithm. This is because you're implicitly using the [base change rule](http://www.mathwords.com/c/change_of_base_formula.htm) to work out the logarithm of `1 / (1  - (r * PV / P))` with base `1+r`.

Comment: that's a bit above my head, is my formula above for `periods_of_time` right or wrong?

Comment: Could you give an example of an unexpected result. It looks fine to me.

Comment: I have edited above, I try to use the formula and it gives not a number